# How can I append a file n times and number the blocks using sed?

Tags: sed

I have a textfile, that has 5000 lines and 3 header lines.

Think of it as one block.

I want to copy 10 blocks in one new file, remove the header for the
second to 10th copy and number the blocks from 0 to 9 in the first column overwriting the first 0 in each line.

I have a clumsy solution and search for a more elegant way.

example:
`file.txt`

```
head1
head2
head3
0;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
0;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
0;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
```

goal:
`goal.txt`

```
head1
head2
head3
0;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
0;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
0;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
1;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
1;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
1;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
2;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
2;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
2;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
3;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
4;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
4;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
4;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
5;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
5;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
6;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
6;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
6;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
7;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
7;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
7;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
8;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
8;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
8;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
9;1; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
9;2; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
9;3; 100.0;200.0;300.0...
```

Solution

```
sed '1,3d' file.txt > fileWithoutHeader.txt

sed 's/^0;/1;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader1.txt
sed 's/^0;/2;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader2.txt
sed 's/^0;/3;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader3.txt
sed 's/^0;/4;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader4.txt
sed 's/^0;/5;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader5.txt
sed 's/^0;/6;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader6.txt
sed 's/^0;/7;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader7.txt
sed 's/^0;/8;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader8.txt
sed 's/^0;/9;/g' fileWithoutHeader.txt > fileWithoutHeader9.txt

cat file.txt > goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader1.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader2.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader3.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader4.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader5.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader6.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader7.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader8.txt>> goal.txt
cat fileWithoutHeader9.txt>> goal.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an incrementing shell parameter:

```
{
    cat file.txt
    for i in {0..9}; do
        sed -n "s/^0;/$i;/p" file.txt
    done
} > goal.txt
```

The `-n` parameter to sed suppresses output, and the `p` flag to the `s` command prints all the lines where a substitution takes place. The whole thing is wrapped in `{}` so we have to redirect the output just once.

Comment: Benjamins answer works fine and is easier to grasp for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -nE '1{x;s/^/0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9/;x};1,3{p;b};/^[^0-9]/{:a;n;//ba;x;s/\S+ //;x};G;s/^0(.*\n)(\S+)/\2\1/;P;d' file file file file file file file file file file
```

Set up the prefix 0 to 9 in the hold space. Print first file headers as normal, all other headers are removed and the head of the prefix table is shortened. All other lines have the beginning `0` replaced by the prefix table lookup.

A more programmatic approach uses parallel:

```
parallel -k sed '1,3d\;s/^0/{}/' file ::: {1..9} | cat file - >outFile
```

Alternative:

```
for n in {1..9}; do sed '1,3d;s/^0/'$n'/' file; done | cat file - >outFile
```

Comment: You can make the first command more cryptic if you use `file{,,,,,,,,,}` ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ahh yes, but then the solution would have the impurity of hint of shell (Bash);}